# How to compile and run java maven project through command line?

Tags: java, sqlite, maven-3, opencsv

I wrote a simple in-memory database program using SQLite 3.27.2.1 and JDBC. I am using OpenCSV 4.6 in this project as well. I have been using Eclipse IDE to run the program so far but I would like to know how to run this maven project via command line. This is my first time using Maven and I have done a bunch of googling but none of the solutions seems to work. I have tried editing the pom.xml file with a list of different plugins and I have tried other solutions that say to do something like `javac -classpath path/to/jar app.java`.

**MS3.java:**

```
package com.ms3.dbx;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MS3
{
    private Connection connection = null;
    private final String URL = "jdbc:sqlite::memory:";

    private final String CSV_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "ms3Interview.csv";
private final String BAD_DATA_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "bad-data-";
    private final String BAD_DATA_EXT = ".csv";

    private DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    private String badDataFilename = BAD_DATA_PATH + df.format(new Date()) + BAD_DATA_EXT;

    private final String LOG_FILE_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Statistics.log";

    private int recordsReceived = 0;
    private int recordsSuccessful = 0;
    private int recordsFailed = 0;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    // Opens connection to in-memory database
    private void openConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed())
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.println("Connection to database established!");
        }
    }

    // Closes connection to database
    private void closeConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        connection.close();
        System.out.print("Database connection closed!");
    }

    // Creates a table named X in database
    private void createTable()
    {
        try
        {
            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS X"
                    + "(A       TEXT,"
                    + " B       TEXT,"
                    + " C       TEXT,"
                    + " D       TEXT,"
                    + " E       TEXT,"
                    + " F       TEXT,"
                    + " G       TEXT,"
                    + " H       TEXT,"
                    + " I       TEXT,"
                    + " J       TEXT);");

        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Reads data from sample.csv file using OpenCSV
    // If there is a blank column in a row, write it to "bad-data-<timestamp>.csv" file
    // Else insert the row into the database
    // Increment recordsReceived for each row in sample.csv file
    // Increment recordsSuccessful for each row that has every column filled with data
    // Increment recordsFailed for each row that has at least one blank column
    private void insertFromCSV()
    {
        try
        {
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_PATH));
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(1).build();

            Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(badDataFilename));

            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);

            final String[] headerRecord = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
            csvWriter.writeNext(headerRecord);

            PreparedStatement pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO X(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");

                String[] nextRecord;
                while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null)
                {
                    recordsReceived++;

                    if (!Arrays.asList(nextRecord).contains(""))
                    {
                        recordsSuccessful++;
                        pstatement.setString(1, nextRecord[0]);
                        pstatement.setString(2, nextRecord[1]);
                        pstatement.setString(3, nextRecord[2]);
                        pstatement.setString(4, nextRecord[3]);
                        pstatement.setString(5, nextRecord[4]);
                        pstatement.setString(6, nextRecord[5]);
                        pstatement.setString(7, nextRecord[6]);
                        pstatement.setString(8, nextRecord[7]);
                        pstatement.setString(9, nextRecord[8]);
                        pstatement.setString(10, nextRecord[9]);
                        pstatement.executeUpdate();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        recordsFailed++;
                        csvWriter.writeNext(nextRecord);
                    }
                }

                csvWriter.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Query the database and print everything to make sure the data is actually being inserted
    private void testDB()
    {
        try
        {
            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM X;");

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            final int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + ",");
                }

                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Log the received, successful, and failed records in a log file
    private void logStats()
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(LOG_FILE_PATH);
            fw.write("Records Received: " + recordsReceived + "\n");
            fw.write("Records Successful: " + recordsSuccessful + "\n");
            fw.write("Records Failed: " + recordsFailed);
            fw.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
        MS3 obj = new MS3();
        obj.openConnection();
        obj.createTable();
        obj.insertFromCSV();
        obj.logStats();
        obj.testDB();
        obj.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ms3.dbx</groupId>
  <artifactId>dbx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dbx</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.27.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set path to execute maven commands with command line...

execute following commands from the path of pom.xml

1. `mvn package` - then there should be a jar file created called dbx.jar
2. `java -cp dbx.jar com.ms3.dbx.MS3`

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: So I did the first command and it generates a file called `dbx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my `eclipse-workspace/dbx/target` path but then I tried the second command and it says `Error: Could not find or load main class com.ms3.dbx.MS3`. I also tried doing the second command again but replacing `dbx.jar` with `dbx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` but then it gives me a bigger error list, which I can put here in the comments if needed.

Comment: Yes, it should be what ever the jar file name as you tried later. If second step worked, then it has run your programme. Error might be due to dependency issues.

Comment: So when I do the second command with `java -cp dbx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.ms3.dbx.MS3` it gives me these errors:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.ms3.dbx.MS3.<clinit>(MS3.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)`

Comment: `at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at com.ms3.dbx.MS3.<clinit>(MS3.java:47)`

Comment: If I just export my project as a runnable JAR file and were to give it to someone else, would they be able to run it okay or would the paths in the program be an issue? Specifically any of the dependencies like sqlite jar or opencsv jar or even any of my paths that I specify for the csv files or log file?

Comment: Dependencies are not a problem since you are using maven. But paths might be a problem. Better to have properties instead of hard coded values.

Comment: There are maven plugins if you want to bundle all the dependencies in to one jar which can be used without maven. U can pass command line arguments when you run that jar which could be a way to pass the paths that are hard coded

Comment: I changed the paths so they are not hard coded. Do I need to do anything else so that I can just give them the jar file that I have and they can run it via `java -jar file.jar`?

Comment: In your Main method, there is an array of strings called args. The values passed when u run the jar file can be accessed through that array by calling arg[0], arg[1] etc. However the paths u have used are just for keeping local data somewhere. So better to keep those paths as the working directory where the jar is placed. No need to take it as an input.

Comment: You need to bundle all the dependencies into one jar file. Use a maven plugin for that.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/5139403